# Handle org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have the following controller logic. However, if I navigate to a non-existing page (e.g. /random-page), I end up with a TemplateInputException. How can I catch this and go to the 404 page?

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "{path:(?!resources|error).*$}", "{path:(?!resources|error).*$}/**" }, headers = "Accept=text/html")
public String index(final HttpServletRequest request) {
    try {
        String path = (String) request.getAttribute(
                HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
        return path.split("/")[1];
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Failed to render the page. {}",e);
        return "error/general";
    }
}
```

Thymeleaf seems to be ignoring the ExceptionHandler:

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ModelAndView handleAllException(Exception ex) {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("error/generic_error");
    model.addObject("errMsg", "this is Exception.class");

    return model;

}
```

Comment: have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 3):

My workaround this problem for spring-boot (`exception` is view with `message` param):

```
@Controller
public class ErrorController implements org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorController {
    private static final String ERROR_PATH = "/error";

    @Autowired
    private ErrorAttributes errorAttributes;

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return ERROR_PATH;
    }

    @RequestMapping(ERROR_PATH)
    public String error(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        Map<String, Object> errorMap = errorAttributes.getErrorAttributes(new ServletRequestAttributes(request), false);
        String exception = (String) errorMap.get("exception");
        if (exception != null && exception.contains("TemplateInputException")) {
            errorMap.put("message", "Неверный запрос");
        }
        model.addAllAttributes(errorMap);
        return "exception";
    }
}
```